# What does "get a bit of" mean?

Tags: meaning

In *Dune (2021)*, in a hot desert like place, Thufir holding umbrella speaking
to Leto:

> Leto: I want to see these harvesting fields myself.
>
> Thufir: I wouldn't recommend it, my lord.
>
> Leto:: Have this Judge of the Change accompany us. A meeting's long overdue.
> And we'll **get a bit of** Imperial protection.

What does "get a bit of" mean?

Comment: The words here have their normal dictionary meanings.  get: obtain or receive.  a bit:  a small amount.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A "bit" is a small amount. So "a bit of Imperial protection" means a small amount of imperial protection. I haven't read the book so I don't know the details, but if taken literally this would mean that he doesn't expect the empire to send a fleet of 100 warships to protect, but just some small amount of protection. Depending on the context that might mean one soldier, or probably something more like the threat that anyone who harms him will be prosecuted or hunted down.

"Get" means to obtain or acquire. So to "get a bit" means to obtain a small amount. He's going to obtain a small amount of imperial protection.

Comment: 'A bit of' can mean 'a useful amount of'.